# How to set default color for HoloColorPicker opacity bar?

Tags: android, android-library

I am using HoloColorPicker Library in my application.
I want to change the default opacity bar value during onCreate.
Don't know where to find the code for it.

[image]

Comment: are you already implementing holopicker it in your app

Answer (score 1):

Just check as described [here.](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker)

```
picker.setOldCenterColor(picker.getColor());
```

Or If you save your color as a string through SharedPreference..Then just do like:

```
picker.setOldCenterColor(Color.parse(your_saved_color_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setColor()` function for it.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker/blob/7c067bcff762320f1ded682a73f59b34867ad93d/src/com/larswerkman/holocolorpicker/ColorPicker.java#L527) it sets color to all bars.

One more thing, you should use this function **after** adding bars to your ColorPicker instance.